# Vanilla Android

Tags: updates, 4.4-kitkat

I hope I don't post this in the wrong place.

It's been known for the life of Android that upgradability of the device is one of main reason when deciding to buy a device. Among the main stream brands, I have owned Samsung Galaxy (the first Samsung Galaxy), LG Optimus G and first generation of (ASUS made) Nexus 7.

Nexus 7 still receives updates until now. I received one or two updates for my Samsung Galaxy and I never got any update on LG Optimus G. According to media, Kitkat update for LG Optimus G is coming (or has come in some countries) but I have not seen it so far.

I have also owned and used few Chinese brand Android devices and they are good for the price but again  the version came with the device is pretty much what you will end up with.

My question is: how hard it is to produce an Android phone that can run Vanilla Android and some future updates (within reasonable time frame). I don't know anything about OS level programming but I would imagine that Google must have some guideline and roadmap about OS Android. If Nexus devices are updatable, why can't other manufacturers choose the same kind of hardware? Can anyone who knows about how OS/hardware working share their knowledge?

It would be awesome if Chinese devices run Vanilla Android and are updatable just as Nexus ones.

[EDIT]
I guess, my other question is: is updatability (or lack of it) more a technical or business reason?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about _why_ OEMs add their own modifications to Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how hard it is to produce an Android phone that can run Vanilla Android

It's not possible at all. Every device (including Nexus devices) needs Android to be *ported* to that device. This means setting it up, from the source code, with the correct drivers, configured correctly for that device. Even if there are no other manufacturer customizations (such as HTC Sense), it needs to be done to make Android work at all.

Even if the device is similar to or shares some components with an existing device, it still won't be compatible with that device's ROMs.

This work needs to be repeated by the manufacturer for each new Android version. This costs money, and for unbranded devices where repeat custom and reputation aren't important, there's really no advantage for the manufacturer, or way for them to recoup their costs.

Comment: Arrgh you beat me to some of the points :) I've modified mine for other details to supplement (hopefully) this answer.

Comment: Sure Android needs to be ported to the device (drivers etc) but shouldn't it be about porting it to hardware (CPU, GPU, etc) level rather than manufaturer brands level? I mean, the Android should be ported to Snapdragon or MTK rather than to Samsung or Lenovo for example? Comparing to Linux (desktop), tho the availability and compatibility of drivers are not as good as for Windows but it is usually expectable that we can install the next version of a linux distro to our PC. I suspect that there is no some kind of database for supported driver for Android?

Comment: But it's not just about the chipset: it's about **all** the hardware, and the way it's configured in that particular device. Only if the two devices have the exact same hardware can they share a ROM image, and even then the "product name" needs to be set correctly in the ROM.

Comment: Thanks. Referring to your other comment, this was a genuine question even though it sounds like a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It is a business reason. Each OEM (manufacturer) wants to stand out in the market through their hardware AND their software. The next time you go to upgrade will you consider learning a new OEM overlay or just a shiny new version of what you already know? (A lot of people go for the latter, they don't care about the OS, their phone is a "HTC" or a "Samsung" not an "Android" device.) There is also another, slightly underhanded reason too.

Also note that EVERY device has its own kernel, drivers etc so there isn't really a 100% vanilla android, it must be ported to each device **including the Nexus line**.

By way of an example: Samsung have their Galaxy S5 flagship running Android, with the Touchwiz overlay. Every Samsung Android device has the Touchwiz Framework. Users get used to the look and feel and general 'Touchwizzyness' of the device. Now in the meantime they develop the Tizen operating system, and skin it to be almost identical to Touchwiz. Now to a user, the underlying operating system is kind of invisible to the user, and functions much the same, except Samsung now have you on their hardware and their own OS.

Here is a [Tizen Screenshot](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/tizen-1.jpg)

Here is a [Touchwiz screenshot](http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/nexusae0_touchwiz2.png)

See what I mean?